# MySQL: ORDER BY or GROUP BY slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have a table in a MySQL DB where certain events are logged. I now want to know which event occurred the least in the last hour for a certain entity domain:

```
SELECT entity_id, COUNT(entity_id) number
FROM event_log
WHERE domain_id=%s AND event_type='%s' AND time>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
GROUP BY entity_id
ORDER BY number ASC;
```

This query takes about 3 seconds on a table with roughly 300.000 rows. Is there a way to speed it up significantly? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try adding a index on `time` or better yet, on `domain_id,event_type,time,entity_id`

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: Can you put that comment in an answer. (Just adding a index for `time` sped the query up 100-fold...)

Comment: Names like `number` and `time` make me itchy because of varying SQL dialects. I would field-quote `time`. _(No critics)_

Comment: Simple hint, you can use EXPLAIN command before your query to know if MySQL use indexes and how many rows he will search in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the table and create Index on domain_id, event_type.